# Dynamic hyperlink from code behind asp.net

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I want dynamic hyperlink on each field in a table column from code behind in asp.net, I implement it thus:

```
table.Append("<td><asp:HyperLink ID='HyperLink1' NavigateUrl='#' runat='server'>" + (string)strNAME + "</asp:HyperLink></td>");
```

on the field but when I run it there is no link to click. it is not effective. what is the correct way of implementing it?

Comment: IMO better use HTML anchor tag instead of using Asp.Net Hyperlink server control unless you are using some sophisticated programming. If just want to make a  simple redirect using HTML anchor element should be first choice. In case you want to make your HyperLink control accessible from code behind after binding it dynamically you can follow up either Andrei or Komal.

Comment: Yea...Never thought about it. The HTML tag is simpler. Thank you very much Superabhat Biswai

Answer (score 1):

You need to approach this in a different way. Server side controls cannot be added as string literals, they should be objects. So what you can do is either add it as a server side control:

```
HyperLink hl = new HyperLink();
hl.ID = "HyperLink1";
hl.NavigateUrl = "#";
hl.Text = (string)strNAME;
TableCell tc = new TableCell();
tc.Controls.Add(hl);
table.Controls.Add(tc);
```

Or add it as a client side link:

```
table.Append("<td><a href='#'>" + (string)strNAME + "</a></td>");
```

Side note: adding table cell to "table" kind of does not make sense because there supposed to be a row, not a table, but I just left your code as is, adjust as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much @Andrei table.Append("<td><a href='#'>" + (string)strNAME + "</a></td>"); works.

Answer (score 0):

Creating hyperlink from code-behind

```
HyperLink hlnk = new HyperLink();
        hlnk.InnerText = (string)strNAME;
        hlnk.ID = "HyperLink1";
        hlnk.NavigateUrl = "/test.aspx";
table.Controls.Add(hlnk);
```

hope it helps